# How can I make browsers cache <textarea> input?

Tags: browser

Imagine you're logged into your account at some website and enter some lengthy text into a form's `<textarea>` element. Then you click submit, only to discover that your session has timed out and instead of having posted your input, you have been logged out. If you log in again, most browsers will still have your input in normal text `<input>` fields cached and suggest it when you click on the respective field. But not for `<textarea>`.

Do Firefox or Chromium (or any other browsers) cache your `<textarea>` input in some hidden way? Is there any option, or add-on, to retrieve cached `<textarea>` input?

Comment: There are usually extensions. What browser are you asking about, specifically?

Comment: [this one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/textarea-cache/) claims to do it for FF

Comment: textarea-cache sounds good, I'll give that a try. Any such extensions for Chromium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think any browsers cache textarea contents by default, but the Firefox [Textarea Cache](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/textarea-cache/) add-on will probably do the right thing.

Or the workaround I use is routinely to *select all* & *copy* before submitting a form, or to use an external text editor to prepare my post, and then paste it back into the textarea when ready.

[It's All Text!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/) is another way of doing this on Firefox.